# Best way to position many elements over image to give interactivity

Tags: html, css

Considering the attached image, I want each "cell" (so to speak) to have a DOM element over it so that it can be clicked, set a background and so on.

I tried making a table and with slight adjustments, made it work for Firefox. I opened other browsers and the fine tunning in Firefox did not apply to them.

How would you do this? There are 465 cells that need to be clickable and all superimposed over the cells in the image with as little error in positioning as possible.

**EDIT:**
Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Francisc/PUPHz/embedded/result/

This is how the table looks in various browsers:
http://89.45.196.35/~francisc/chrome.jpg
http://89.45.196.35/~francisc/firefox.jpg
http://89.45.196.35/~francisc/ie.jpg

Thank you.
[image]

Comment: please make a jsfiddle to show what adjustments you made in firefox - maybe there is a simple cross-browser adjustment to your code...

Comment: Adjustments are made using :nth-child on tr and tweaking heights slightly for child td.

Comment: @Francisc, please do make a fiddle.. we cannot guess what is wrong..

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Francisc/PUPHz/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do, it's messy but it could work. Make a single div fit over the top left and find out the best width and height (Guessing you know that from the table that you tried)

You will have to make the image go under the divs so I think you have to give it an overlay attribute or something like that (Can't remember what it's called) so with that in mind you have the class for each div to be width: XXpx height: XXpx float:left and that should be it. From there you can make the :hover class to make the background change and a selected class also if you need to.

Hope it helps